# How to replace nodes in quicktab?

Tags: hooks, blocks

How can I replace nodes in quicktabs on click of a link?

Answer (score 0):

i guess your using the quicktabs block. if so you can configure here **admin/structure/blocks**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I am calling nodes in quiktab directly but those nodes should get  changed on click of the link

Comment: ah - you want to change the content of a tab, after a click ? then you need to hook into the quicktab logic ..